# Question on polynomials

Tags: polynomials, roots

[image]

What I know is that if the above said equation has three equal roots that meant that the above equation can be written as (x-q)^3*(x-w)*(x-e)...
Now do we have to compare this equation with the given one to find the conditions( taking sum of roots at a time,two at a time,three at a time,four at a time,five at a time) or is there any other way to solve such questions.. Any help will be useful...Thanks in advance......

Comment: Perhaps the fact that the derivative and second derivative also share the same root might help?

Comment: @copper.hat what you are saying is that applicable for all polynomials????

Comment: If a polynomial has the form $p(x) = (x-r)^m q(x)$ then you must have $p^{(k)}(r) = 0$ for $k=0,...,m-1$.

Comment: @copper.hat  calculation will become tedious....

Comment: Have you even tried? The root is $a$.

Comment: @copper.hat working on that only...

Comment: @copper.hat  a is the root...

Comment: That might help?

Comment: @copper.hat Got one option correct

Comment: @copper.hat One more option is correct...

Comment: @copper.hat Got it thanks a lot.........

Comment: Well done! ${}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for your help.....